# Github Actions, I'm getting mistake like this Error: Process completed with exit code 1

Tags: laravel, github, github-actions

I'm struggling with this functionality of github action . I'm new with this and I'm using Laravel7.30 /php 7.4  and vue ... . I was thinking about a general code to do easy actions for basics necessities . I'm new and I only requires the normal workflow , Can you help me or provide a script ? please. I'm lost. I'd like that you guys could share me a good tutorial, I've read some tutorials but I'm still confused and help me please . thanks.

```html
name: tests

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - development
  pull_request:
    branches:
      - development
  schedule:
    - cron: '0 0 * * *'

jobs:
  tests:
    runs-on: ubuntu-20.04

    strategy:
      fail-fast: true
      matrix:
        php: [7.4]
        laravel: [^7.0]

    name: PHP ${{ matrix.php }} - Laravel ${{ matrix.laravel }}

    steps:
      - name: Checkout code
        uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Setup PHP
        uses: shivammathur/setup-php@v2
        with:
          php-version: ${{ matrix.php }}
          tools: composer:v2
          coverage: none

      - name: Install dependencies
        run: |
          composer require "illuminate/contracts=${{ matrix.laravel }}" --no-update
          composer update --prefer-dist --no-interaction --no-progress
        
      - name: Generate Key
        run: php artisan key:generate

      - name: Execute tests
        run: vendor/bin/phpunit --verbose
```